# Is there a widely-understood visual metaphor for using part or all of an existing item to make a new one?

Tags: info-visualisation, visual-cues, visual-vocabulary

I'm looking to convey the following functionality to users: able to take part or all of an existing short text entry and make a new, related text entry from it.

For example, if a user encounters the comment: "*I like cold soup because it is so refreshing on a hot summer day*," we offer the user the ability to take part or all of that quoted text and make a new, related question out of it (e.g. create a question for the community to discuss *"Is cold soup refreshing on a hot summer day?"*)

Absurd example, but I hope it conveys what I'm getting at.

Comment: Wow, great challenge. How much space do you have to work with?

Comment: Trying to convey the idea in something sized like an icon, drawtheweb

Comment: This appears to be descending into a poll of icon suggestions rather than an answer to the question. Icon requests themselves are off-topic here for this reason (none of the answers below specifically answer the question, they're all just suggestions that people end up voting on their favourite). It was [recently discussed](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/edit-icon-for-x-questions-not-too-localized-to-visual-metaphor-requests-and-re) on Meta about whether these questions should be made more valid, but I'm not sure this particular question is a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, interesting... maybe "remix", "refresh", "fork", "split", or "post"?

[image]
([source](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/72019/26/refresh_reload_synchronize_icon))

[image]
([source](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/71766/26/child_new_post_icon))

[image]
([source](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/83308/32/fork_github_icon))

[image]
(icon for a [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/) "rebound")

[image]
([via](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/82192/16/expand_full_screen_icon))

[image]
([via](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/82193/16/expand_icon))

Comment: I actually think the 'fork' icon to be viable in this context.

Comment: +1 for fork that is the only one out of those examples that seems relevant to me.  Plus, it is exactly what the use case described above is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Focussing on a single component of a multi-part object might be the visualization you're looking for. This is rough:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Certainly nothing "widely-understood".  If you need to have a symbol know that people won't understanding it initially but can learn it.

Perhaps something pseudo mathematical like

### **≈>**

Comment: Terrific point about users learning. Gracias. -Mark

Answer (score -1):

How about something like the rough drill icons here, as in "drilling down" into the topic?

[image]

Or

[image]

Or

[image]

And one more I found on a web search:

[image]

Last image found on http://sketchybiz.blogspot.com/2007/07/drilling-down-to-ordinary-level.html and probably owned by them